# Using CIP rules in a bicyclic compound with carbonyl subsituent

Tags: nomenclature, stereochemistry

In bicyclo[2.2.1]heptan-2-one, arrange the numbered groups according to CIP rules:

[image: bicyclo[2.2.1]heptan-2-one]

Group 1 will have highest priority because oxygen atom is attached to 1. (It can be considered as two oxygen atoms).

Group 4 will have least priority due to least atomic number among the numbered groups.

But I am confused about order of priority of group 2 and 3. Both have same atoms. (So I will check the next atom which is also same.)

Comment: Group 2 has -CH2-C(CHH); group 3 has -CH2-C(CCH) where (XYZ) means that the carbon is bonded to XYZ atoms. I mean, you already used this rule to determine that 1 was the highest, didn't you. 1 is -C(OOC) whereas 2 and 3 are both -C(CHH). Since O > C in atomic number 1 > 2,3. Same goes for 2 and 3 you just need to go one carbon further.

Comment: OK. So 3 has more priority.

Comment: Yup it does, which gives you an *S* configuration, I think.

Comment: Also note that the given compound has a second chirality center at the other bridgehead.

Comment: @orthocresol: It's an S-configuration if the methylene 3 is above the plane of the 6-membered ring. I presume that your "I think" considers this point.

Comment: @user55119 yes, an important point. I must admit, I have no recollection of what I was thinking at that time. :-)